# execute specific query in kettle after filter

Tags: pentaho, kettle

In my diagram at a certain point, I have a filter rows. If the result is TRUE I would like to do a SELECT otherwise (FALSE) another kind of select. I did it with two `input table` objects.

Actually, after the filter rows, both the two `input table` are executed may be because are initialized at the start. I've also tried with the SQL script but it seems to has the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, this is how PDI works.  All the steps are initialized at the same time which can cause issues in exactly this scenario.  Is your specific problem that one of the table inputs may not get any rows and this blows up?

See here: http://forums.pentaho.com/archive/index.php/t-78324.html

Various solutions, are you "executing for each row"? in which case you can dynamically build the SQL in a string.  Otherwise need a bit more info to devise a solution - bit tricky.

Comment: thank you. I've tried to use executing for each row as a trick, without parameters (I don't need parameters), but if I did not specify parameters it throws `no parameters defined`. Could be asolution adding fake WHERE 1=? and previously a constant with values 1?

Comment: thanks but at the end I have opted for a different solution, using two different transformations. I think that is more readable.